# Why is Google groups refusing to add a g-suite address?

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, google-groups

A friend is trying to make me a member of a google group, but he's receiving an error message saying: "One person has decided to opt out of being directly added to groups".

My address is a G-suite e-mail address and I'm the administrator. I went through the settings of the admin console, but didn't find any particular setting related to this.

Why is Google Groups automatically refusing to add my address?

### EDIT

I asked the person to add another email address that belongs to another domain, but that is a secondary domain in the same G-suite account and this account got added normally, so this might help in diagnosing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this issue. In the [settings](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!usersettings/general) there are two check boxes to allow group admins to automatically add you or invite you to their groups. Once these settings are enabled, it is possible to be added or invited to groups.

Source: [https://technical.sabhlokcity.com](https://technical.sabhlokcity.com/2013/04/one-person-has-decided-to-opt-out-of-being-direct-added-to-groups/)